# Filter AWS resources using regex in aws-sdk-go

Tags: go, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-go

So I have some different types of aws resources tagged as `xxx/yyy/<generated_id>`. I need to fetch them using go-sdk.

Here is a sample code for subnets, the filters look the same for every other resource.

This doesn't work.

```
var resp *ec2.DescribeSubnetsOutput
resp, err = d.ec2Client().DescribeSubnets(&ec2.DescribeSubnetsInput{
    Filters: []*ec2.Filter{
        {
            Name:   aws.String("vpc-id"),
            Values: []*string{&d.VpcId},
        },
        {
            Name:   aws.String(fmt.Sprintf(`tag:"xxx/yyy.[*]"`),
            Values: []*string{aws.String("owned")},
        },
    },
})
```

This does:

`` aws ec2 describe-subnets --filters `Name=tag:"xxx/yyy.[*]",Values=owned` ``

I'm obviously doing something wrong, can someone point out what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the API documentation to suggest that `DescribeSubnets` accepts a regular expression in filter names: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeSubnets.html

If it works in the CLI, that's likely something the CLI is doing on top of what the SDK offers. The Go SDK is like any other AWS SDK; it exposes the AWS API in a language-specific way. The AWS CLI adds convenience features on top of the API to make it more useful on the command line, but that doesn't mean those features are exposed by the API or any published SDK.

Comment: I was afraid of the same. I did go through the document myself, sometime ago. I was hoping someone would know an alternative maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I stepped with this problem recently, my issue was the version of the sdk I was using;

> Filters: [ ]*ec2.Filter{

is for v1 sdk mod and it was not working as I was importing ***github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws***,  while

> Filters: [ ]types.Filter{

is for v2 and this one worked in my case.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-sdk-for-go-version-2-general-availability/